# Getting selected ItemsControl Item

Tags: vb.net, xaml, mvvm, uwp, windows-10-universal

Currentlly creating my windows 10 App, and I'm trying to move a rectangle on canvas following mvvm pattern. The code below works but I broke mvvm by using a uielemnt in my viewmodel PointerDragEvent.

```
   Dim rec = TryCast(e.OriginalSource, Button)
   Dim selrecitem = TryCast(rec.DataContext, RectItem)
```

**Question**

Is there a non hacky/proper way of doing this?

How can I retrieve the item I click on and pass it to my viewmodel?

All items on canvas will be dynamically created.

```
<Page
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App11"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:Interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity" xmlns:Core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
x:Class="App11.MainPage"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.DataContext>
        <local:myviewmodel/>
    </Grid.DataContext>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="8*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>

    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="11*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ItemsControl x:Name="itemsControl" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding myrectangles, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="ManipulationDelta">
                <Core:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding Mode=OneWay}" MethodName="PointerDrag"/>
            </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
        </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas Background="White">

                </Canvas>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

            <DataTemplate>
                <Button x:Name="PageItem" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="DodgerBlue" Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding Height}" ManipulationMode="TranslateX, TranslateY" IsHitTestVisible="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=SelectToolButton, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Command="{Binding SendMyDC, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
                    <Button.RenderTransform>
                        <CompositeTransform TranslateX="{Binding X}" TranslateY="{Binding Y}"/>
                    </Button.RenderTransform>

                </Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>

</Grid>
```

Viewmodel

```
Public Class myviewmodel
Implements INotifyPropertyChanged
Private Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(Optional propertyName As String = "")
    RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
End Sub

Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
Private _myrectangles As New ObservableCollection(Of RectItem)
Public Property myrectangles As ObservableCollection(Of RectItem)
    Get
        Return _myrectangles
    End Get
    Set(value As ObservableCollection(Of RectItem))
        _myrectangles = value
        NotifyPropertyChanged()
    End Set
End Property

Public Sub New()
    Dim newrect As New RectItem
    newrect.Height = 100
    newrect.Width = 150
    newrect.X = 50
    newrect.Y = 50
    _myrectangles.Add(newrect)
End Sub

Public Sub PointerDrag(sender As Object, e As ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs)
    Dim dx_point = e.Delta.Translation.X
    NotifyPropertyChanged()
    Dim dy_point = e.Delta.Translation.Y
    NotifyPropertyChanged()
    Dim rec = TryCast(e.OriginalSource, Button)
    Dim selrecitem = TryCast(rec.DataContext, RectItem)

    selrecitem.X += dx_point
    selrecitem.Y += dy_point
End Sub
End Class
```

RectItemClass

```
Public Class RectItem
Implements INotifyPropertyChanged
Private Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(Optional propertyName As String = "")
    RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
End Sub

Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

Public Property X As Double
    Get
        Return m_X
    End Get
    Set
        m_X = Value
        NotifyPropertyChanged()
    End Set
End Property
Private m_X As Double
Public Property Y As Double
    Get
        Return m_Y
    End Get
    Set
        m_Y = Value
        NotifyPropertyChanged()
    End Set
End Property
Private m_Y As Double
Public Property Width As Double
    Get
        Return m_Width
    End Get
    Set
        m_Width = Value
        NotifyPropertyChanged()
    End Set
End Property
Private m_Width As Double
Public Property Height As Double
    Get
        Return m_Height
    End Get
    Set
        m_Height = Value
        NotifyPropertyChanged()
    End Set
End Property
Private m_Height As Double
End Class
```

**Edit #1 Instead of using an item control I used an ListView/Listbox and binded the selected item to a property in my vewimodel. With the listview there is some problem getting the item presenter aligned with the item its's presenting  and with listbox, the pointer up event doesn't fire.**

```
<ListView x:Name="itemsControl" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding myrectangles, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" Background="#FFF2F2F2"  SelectedItem="{Binding selectedrec, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">

        <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="ManipulationDelta">
                <Core:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding Mode=OneWay}" MethodName="PointerDrag"/>
            </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
            <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="PointerPressed">
                <Core:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding Mode=OneWay}" MethodName="PointerPressed"/>
            </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
            <!--<Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="PointerReleased">
                <Core:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding Mode=OneWay}" MethodName="Up"/>
            </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>-->
        </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>



        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas Background="White">

                </Canvas>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
       <!--<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">

                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <ContentPresenter/>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>


            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>-->
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>

            <DataTemplate>
                <Rectangle x:Name="PageItem" Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding Height}"  Fill="Transparent" Stroke="DodgerBlue" ManipulationMode="TranslateX, TranslateY" IsHitTestVisible="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=SelectToolButton, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >


                    <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                        <CompositeTransform TranslateX="{Binding X}" TranslateY="{Binding Y}"/>
                    </Rectangle.RenderTransform>

                </Rectangle>

            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>

</Grid>
```

Updated ViewModel

```
 Public _selectedrec As New RectItem
 Public Property selectedrec As RectItem
    Get
        Return _selectedrec
    End Get
    Set(value As RectItem)
        _selectedrec = value
        NotifyPropertyChanged()
    End Set
End Property

 Public Sub PointerDrag(sender As Object, e As ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs)

    Dim dx_point = e.Delta.Translation.X
    NotifyPropertyChanged()
    Dim dy_point = e.Delta.Translation.Y
    NotifyPropertyChanged()


    selectedrec.X += dx_point
    NotifyPropertyChanged()
    selectedrec.Y += dy_point
    NotifyPropertyChanged()



End Sub
```

**Example of problems**

**No itemcontainerstyle - When trying to drag object snaps to 0,0 of canvas**

[image]

**MyHalfFix - Uncomment the ItemContainerStyle - Everything works correctly what im aiming for**

[image]

**The Overall Problem when implemented in the actual program**

[image]

The red Item is the listviewitem presenter. It's being drawn correctly but the positioning is not aligned with the drawn rectangle it always snaps to point 0,0 of canvas. I can make it transparent but as you can also see when drawing the rectangle it doesn't follow the cursor correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [InvokeCommandAction](https://github.com/Microsoft/XamlBehaviors/wiki/InvokeCommandAction) for the `ManipulationDelta` event will avoid breaking the MVVM pattern. `InvokeCommandAction` can pass a parameter to the `viewmodel` and we can pass the `selecteditem` by the parameter. The object of `ManipulationDelta` should be the button instead of the `ItemsControl` and the `InvokeCommandAction` will work, what you actually drag is the button itself. Updated code as follows:

XAML

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Name="root">
  ...
       <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
               <Button x:Name="PageItem" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="DodgerBlue" Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding Height}" ManipulationMode="TranslateX, TranslateY" IsHitTestVisible="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=SelectToolButton, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
                   <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                       <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="ManipulationDelta" SourceObject="{Binding ElementName=PageItem}">
                           <Core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.SendMyDC, ElementName=root}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"></Core:InvokeCommandAction>
                           <Core:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=root, Mode=OneWay}" MethodName="PointerDrag" />
                       </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                   </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                   <Button.RenderTransform>
                       <CompositeTransform TranslateX="{Binding X}" TranslateY="{Binding Y}"/>
                   </Button.RenderTransform>
               </Button>
           </DataTemplate>
       </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
   </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

myviewmodel

```
Public Class myviewmodel  
...
Private m_sendCommand As IDelegateCommand
Public Property SendMyDC As IDelegateCommand
    Get
        Return m_sendCommand
    End Get
    Protected Set(value As IDelegateCommand)
        m_sendCommand = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Sub New()
    Me.SendMyDC = New DelegateCommand(AddressOf ExecuteSendMyDC)
    Dim newrect As New RectItem
    newrect.Height = 100
    newrect.Width = 150
    newrect.X = 50
    newrect.Y = 50
    _myrectangles.Add(newrect)
End Sub

Dim selrecitem As RectItem
Public Sub PointerDrag(sender As Object, e As ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs)
    Dim dx_point = e.Delta.Translation.X
    NotifyPropertyChanged()
    Dim dy_point = e.Delta.Translation.Y
    NotifyPropertyChanged()
    'Dim rec = TryCast(e.OriginalSource, Button)
    'Dim selrecitem = TryCast(rec.DataContext, RectItem)
    If selrecitem IsNot Nothing Then
        selrecitem.X += dx_point
        selrecitem.Y += dy_point
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ExecuteSendMyDC(param As Object)
    selrecitem = CType(param, RectItem)
End Sub 
End Class
```

DelegateCommand class

```
Public Class DelegateCommand
Implements IDelegateCommand
Private _execute As Action(Of Object)
Private _canExecute As Func(Of Object, Boolean)
#Region "Constructors"
Public Sub New(execute As Action(Of Object), canExecute As Func(Of Object, Boolean))
    Me._execute = execute
    Me._canExecute = canExecute
End Sub
Public Sub New(execute As Action(Of Object))
    Me._execute = execute
    Me._canExecute = AddressOf Me.AlwaysCanExecute
End Sub
#End Region
#Region "IDelegateCommand"
Private Function AlwaysCanExecute(param As Object) As Boolean
    Return True
End Function
Public Function CanExecute(parameter As Object) As Boolean Implements System.Windows.Input.ICommand.CanExecute
    Return _canExecute(parameter)
End Function
Public Event CanExecuteChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Implements System.Windows.Input.ICommand.CanExecuteChanged
Public Sub Execute(parameter As Object) Implements System.Windows.Input.ICommand.Execute
    _execute(parameter)
End Sub

Public Sub RaiseCanExecuteChanged() Implements IDelegateCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged
    RaiseEvent CanExecuteChanged(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
End Sub
#End Region
End Class
Public Interface IDelegateCommand
    Inherits ICommand
    Sub RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
End Interface
```

DelegateCommand is a common class for you further invoking other commands. More details please reference [Command binding inside DataTemplate](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Command-binding-inside-3cef5eea).

Comment: I tried implementing your code provided but it didn't work. Nothing is being raised when I start dragging. I did find a work around though i'll update the question

Comment: @Twinnaz I uploaded the completed demo which I tested well to [github](https://github.com/sunteenwu/PersonalDemo/tree/master/CBInding)  you can reference, if still have issues please feel free to let me know.

Comment: It works well in the example I provided thank you. Unfortunately it doesn't work in the whole program im trying to implement it in. The button will be dynamically drawn. I can provide the code but I think its too much to post on here.

Comment: @Twinnaz if conveniently , could you please upload to github or onedrive or somewhere. You know its hard for me to guess what's wrong of it without code.  Otherwise I can only guess.

Comment: @Twinnaz I tested it on my side and can reproduce. This is completely a new issue about style. The ListBox has its own layout, what you actually dragged is the inside control you defined in item template, not the listbox item itself. Why did you use the listbox? As work around you found, and then add a full color with the rectangle will meet your requirements,right?

Comment: I used a list box as a work around because it had the selecteditem property that I can easily bind to a property in my viewmodel. I did update the question see edit#1. basically I was having trouble with the styling but just left the item presenter transparent.  I do like your idea in the sense that its the object is handling its own drag rather than the listbox itself, but your answer did answer my first question I posted thank you.

Comment: My new problem is out of scope for this question that's why I didn't provide addition code. Sorry for the confusion